# Can I use a service like Scribd/Oyster with the Kindle eReader?

Tags: kindle, epub, ebook-readers, calibre, conversion

I'm not talking about Kindle fire. The  $79 one.

It doesn't have to directly support it.

My thinking is:

- If Kindle support the epub format
- Scribd offers epub
- There's software out there like Calibre that can convert between formats

I should be able to use services like scribd/oyster then. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What do you mean by service?  Perhaps you have in mind something like a Calibre recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you manage to download from somewhere an ePub file, then you can convert it to mobi format using a software as Calibre. This would allow you to read such books on a Kindle.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you are right, and as @clami219 said you could use a software to transform one format into the other. This has nothing to do with Scribd or Oyster. **But** you will be getting problems at converting when those ebooks are provided with an DRM.

Answer (score 1):

I use [this website, EPUB2Kindle](http://epub2kindle.com/) to convert from one format to other formats. It's fast and reliable. They have a whole series of convertors with different domains.